# Matplotlib create axes in external function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to code a function that generates an axes with a plot in it to be able to add it to a larger plot.

It should have the following structure:

```py
def createAxes(data):
    # create Axes object and plot data in it
    return axes


# somewhere else
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, figsize=(10, 5))
    
axs[0] = createAxes(data1)
axs[0].set_title('data 1')
axs[1] = createAxes(data2)
axs[1].set_title('data 2');
```

I have already tried to use `plt.axes()`, for example:

```
def createAxes(data):
    plot = plt.axes()
    plot.plot(1,1, color="black")
    return plot
```

For this I get overlaying plots.

Comment: Are you looking for the "subplot" ability?

Comment: @TimRoberts I know how to do "normal" subplots. However, I wondered if it is possible to create an axes decoupled from the plot inside a function, which I could reuse.

Comment: I think you may want to pass the Axes as an argument to the function `def plotting_function(ax, data, title):` and then call it like `plotting_function(axs[0], data1, 'Data 1')` etc. You can't create an axes on it's own (i.e. without a figure) and then "attach" it to a figure.